# Angular Mat-Icons Background Color When Double Clicked Many Times

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this multiple mat-icons problem, when the other one double clicked the background of the 3 displayed this.

[image: See screenshot here]

Here's a sample stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjiiyn?file=app/icon-overview-example.html

Step to replicate: Clicke it fast like 3 times.

Can someone know who to fix this issue? Badly need help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Create a working stackblitz example or at least show all relevant code. We have no idea how this is supposed to work or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @G.Tranter I added some steps to replicate on stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard triple-click selection behavior of the browser which causes the entire row to be selected. Since the icons are font icons, they can be selected just like text. Other than the visual selection indication, what actual problem is it causing in your application? There is more than one way to disable text selection in a browser, but an easy one is via CSS with `user-select: none;`